# Find the mistake in titlesec usage : DO print the chapter and section numbers in the text

Tags: titlesec

at some point during my thesis writing I removed the numbers from the chapter and section heading, and now I cannot spot which line is removing them. I want to have the numbers/letters there again. Sorry this is not a working example.

I suspect the mistake is in the line

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{\normalfont\huge\filcenter\bfseries}
{\thechapter}
{0.5em}
{}
```

, because it prints the default styling of chapter **with number** if I remove it. I thought \thechapter also prints the number (in my case alphabetic letter), but it does not do it in my case. What is the right expression for the line if I want the number there?

Here is the document

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\MakeInnerQuote{|}

\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\setstretch{1.5}

\setlength{\parindent}{5mm}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\resetHeadWidth}{\fancy@setoffs}
\makeatother

\usepackage[bottom,hang]{footmisc}
\setlength\footnotemargin{15pt} % align footnote text for multiline footnotes
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{%
    \kern -3pt
    \hrule width \textwidth height 0.5pt
    \kern 2pt
}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Linux Biolinum O}
%[BoldFont = {Caecilia LT Std},
%ItalicFont = {Caecilia LT Std}]
%\setmonofont[Color={000000}]{Inconsolata}
%\setromanfont{Times New Roman}
%\setsansfont{Arial}
%\setmonofont[Color={000000}]{Courier New}
%\renewcommand{\acsfont}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[chapter,nottoc]{tocbibind} %index in table of contents
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% section chapter style global
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@section}{\thechapter.}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% styling of headings
\usepackage[raggedright,nobottomtitles]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0.5em}
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-5em}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{\normalfont\huge\filcenter\bfseries}
{\thechapter}
{0.5em}
{}

%\titlelabel{\thetitle\quad}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{20pt}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\LARGE\itshape\bfseries}{\thesection}{0.5em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\normalfont\Large\itshape\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{0.5em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]{\normalfont\large\itshape\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{0.5em}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\normalfont\normalsize\itshape\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{0.5em}{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% bibliography and citation styling
\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw,
edsuper=true,
namefont=smallcaps,
useprefix=true,
ibidemfont=smallcaps,
idemfont=smallcaps,
idembibformat=dash,
shorthandibid=true,
backref=false,
backrefstyle=none,
hyperref=true,
isbn=false,
backend=biber,
citereset=chapter,
bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
%\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
%\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{page}{#1}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}

% all authors should be separated by slashes
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addnbspace\slash\space}
%\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addnbspace\slash\space} 
\renewcommand*{\bibmultinamedelim}{\addnbspace\slash\space}
%\renewcommand*{\bibfinalnamedelim}{\addnbspace\slash\space}

% the separator before the location should be a dot, not a comma
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
    \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
    \printlist{location}%
    \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%
    \newunit}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
and={/},
andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},
byeditor         = {{herausgegeben von}{hg\adddot\addabthinspace v\adddot}},
byeditortr       = {{herausgegeben und \lbx@lfromlang \"ubersetzt von}%
        {hg\adddotspace und \lbx@sfromlang \"ubers\adddot\ v\adddot}},
byeditorco       = {{herausgegeben und kommentiert von}%
        {hg\adddotspace und komm\adddot\ v\adddot}},
byeditoran       = {{herausgegeben und erl\"autert von}%
        {hg\adddotspace und erl\"aut\adddot\ v\adddot}},
byeditorin       = {{herausgegeben und mit einer Einleitung versehen von}%
        {hg\adddotspace und mit einer Einl\adddot\ vers\adddot\ v\adddot}},
byeditorfo       = {{herausgegeben und mit einem Vorwort versehen von}%
        {hg\adddotspace und mit einem Vorw\adddot\ vers\adddot\ v\adddot}},
byeditoraf       = {{herausgegeben und mit einem Nachwort versehen von}%
        {hg\adddotspace und mit einem Nachw\adddot\ vers\adddot\ v\adddot}},
byeditortrco     = {{herausgegeben, \lbx@lfromlang \"ubersetzt und kommentiert von}%
        {hg., \lbx@sfromlang \"ubers\adddot\ und komm\adddot\ v\adddot}},
byeditortran     = {{herausgegeben, \lbx@lfromlang \"ubersetzt und erl\"autert von}%
        {hg., \lbx@sfromlang \"ubers\adddot\ und erl\"aut\adddot\ v\adddot}},
byeditortrin     = {{herausgegeben, \lbx@lfromlang \"ubersetzt und mit einer Einleitung versehen von}%
        {hg., \lbx@sfromlang \"ubers\adddot\ und mit einer Einl\adddot\ vers\adddot\ v\adddot}},
byeditortrfo     = {{herausgegeben, \lbx@lfromlang \"ubersetzt und mit einem Vorwort versehen von}},
editor = {{Hg\adddot}},
editors = {{Hg\adddot}}
}

\usepackage{url}
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{9000}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{9000}
\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{9000}

% make title italic
%\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{\ifsingletitle
%   {\setunit{}}% Löschen des \nametitledelim, falls kein Titel ausgegeben wird
%   {\ifboolexpr{
%           test {\ifentrytype{review}}
%           and
%           not test {\iffieldundef{xref}}
%       }
%       {\printtext[review]{\bbx@review{\thefield{xref}}}}
%       {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
%               \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}%
%       \ifbool{cbx:addyear}
%       {\iffieldundef{year}
%           {}
%           {\titleyeardelim\parentext{\printfield{year}}}}{}}}


\usepackage[withpage]{acronym}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{xargs}                      % Use more than one optional parameter in a new commands
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}  % Coloured text etc.
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,prependcaption,textsize=tiny]{todonotes}




\newenvironment{indentt}{\begin{list}{}%
        {\setlength{\leftmargin}{0.5cm}}%
        \item[]}{\end{list}}

\defbibheading{caption}{
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}
    \section*{#1}%
    \markboth{#1}{#1}
}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% multind fuer andere Register
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multind}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% glossaries fuer Personenregister
\usepackage[nopostdot,toc,section]{glossaries}

\glsaddkey*% star version needed as default value needs expanding
{nn}% key
{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}nn}% default value
{\glsentrynn}% command analogous to \glsentrytext
{\Glsentrynn}% command analogous to \Glsentrytext
{\glsnn}% command analogous to \glstext
{\Glsnn}% command analogous to \Glstext
{\GLSnn}% command analogous to \GLStext

\glsaddkey*% star version needed as default value needs expanding
{fn}% key
{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}fn}% default value
{\glsentryfn}% command analogous to \glsentrytext
{\Glsentryfn}% command analogous to \Glsentrytext
{\glsfn}% command analogous to \glstext
{\Glsfn}% command analogous to \Glstext
{\GLSfn}% command analogous to \GLStext
\newcommand*{\entryurl}[1]{%
    \glsdoifexists{#1}%
    {%
        \glsletentryfield{\thisurl}{#1}{useri}%
        \expandafter\url\expandafter{\thisurl}%
    }%
}
\newglossarystyle{urls}
{% based on list style
    \setglossarystyle{list}%
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
        \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]
        \glspostdescription \hfill##2\qquad\qquad%
        \\
        \glossentrydesc{##1}}
}
\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{person-glossary}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% new commands
\newcommand{\id}[1]{#1\,\index{#1}}

\newcommand{\z}[3]{\footcite[#3][#2]{#1}}
\newcommand{\q}[1]{\enquote{#1}}
\newcommand{\be}[1]{#1\index{begriffe}{#1}}
\newcommand{\beg}[2]{#1\index{begriffe}{#2}}
\newcommand{\ibe}[1]{\index{begriffe}{#1}}
\newcommand{\p}[1]{#1\index{personen}{#1}}
\newcommand{\pe}[2]{#1\index{personen}{#2}}
\newcommand{\bib}[1]{#1\index{bibelstellen}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ibib}[1]{\index{bibelstellen}{#1}}
\newcommand{\bibe}[2]{#1\index{bibelstellen}{#2}}
\newcommandx{\imp}[2][1=]{\todo[linecolor=red,backgroundcolor=red!25,bordercolor=red,#1]{#2}}

\renewcommand*{\citenamepunct}{\addcomma\space} % in fussnoten komma hinter dem autor
\renewcommand*{\locationpublisherpunct}{\adddot\space}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% pagestyle

\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\ifnum\value{chapter}=0 \thechapter\else\thechapter.\fi\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\rightmark}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}
\cfoot{}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% table of contents styling
\usepackage{titletoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\titlecontents*{paragraph}[7.5em]{\small}{\thecontentslabel}{}{~(\thecontentspage)}[~---\ ]
%\titlecontents{section}[3.8em]{}{\contentslabel{2.3em}}{\hspace*{-2.3em}}{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}






\hyphenation{Mit-tel-stre-cken-ra-ke-ten Ver-ei-ni-gung Lu-xem-burg Lan-des-vor-sitz-en-der Meck-len-burg-Vor-pom-mern Weih-nach-ten Aus-ein-an-der-setz-ung Ver-ant-wort-ung Kom-mu-nis-ti-schen So-w-jet-uni-on hun-der-te Stell-ver-tre-ter}


\makeindex{begriffe}
%\makeindex{personen}
\makeindex{bibelstellen}

\addbibresource{literatur.bib}
\addbibresource{predigten.bib}
\addbibresource{quellen.bib}
\addbibresource{lexika.bib}
\addbibresource{unverquellen.bib}

\begin{document}

    \frontmatter   


    \newgeometry{inner=2cm,outer=2cm,bottom=2cm,top=3cm}
    \resetHeadWidth

    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\sloppy}
    \tableofcontents
    \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip-10pt}
    \markboth{Inhaltsverzeichnis}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}



    \mainmatter
    \newgeometry{inner=2cm,outer=2cm,bottom=2cm,top=3cm}
    \resetHeadWidth
    \setcounter{page}{1}

    \setlength{\emergencystretch}{1em}
    \input{vorwort}
    \input{MethodischerTeil}
    \input{HistorischerTeil}
    \input{DiePredigten}
    \input{SystematischerTeil}
    \input{wirkungsgeschichte}

    \input{glossary}

%   \restoregeometry
%   \resetHeadWidth
    \chapter{Anhang}
    \section*{Dokumente}    
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{tisa}
        \caption{Holzschnitt 1/50 mit dem Titel "Wir bleiben hier. Schliesst euch an. Rostock. Oktober '89.", Elisabeth "Tisa" von der Schulenburg}
        \label{fig:tisa}
    \end{figure}
    \pagebreak
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{fragebogen}
        \caption{Fragebogenvorlage}
        \label{fig:fragebogen}
    \end{figure}
    \pagebreak
    %   \include{chronologie}

    \setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}
    \printbibliography[keyword=unverquellen,title=Verzeichnis der unveröffentlichten Quellen,heading=caption]
    \printbibliography[keyword=quellen,title=Quellenverzeichnis,heading=caption]
    \printbibliography[keyword=lexika,title=Lexika,heading=caption]
    \printbibliography[keyword=literatur,title=Literaturverzeichnis,heading=caption]

    \printglossary[style=urls,nopostdot=true,nogroupskip,title=Personenregister,toctitle=Personenregister]
    \pagebreak
    \printindex{begriffe}{Sachregister}
%   \printindex{personen}{Personenregister}
    \pagebreak
    \printindex{bibelstellen}{Bibelstellenregister}
    \pagebreak
    \input{predigtanhang}

%   \printbibliography
    %\include{danksagung}

    % ö Ö Ü ü Ä ä

    %\include{lebenslauf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\chapter{Some chapter}
\section{Some section}
\subsection{Some subsection}
\subsubsection{Some subsubsection}` directly after `\mainmatter` and check whether the headings are numbered. In my tests they are numbered, so I suspect that the problem is in some of the files that you did not include. (I had to comment out all the `\input` statements and some `\usepackage` for a non-standard style file to make it compile.)

Comment: thanks, I'll try to track it down this way, sorry for the messy question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use `block` option instead of `hang`

So the correct line is :

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\normalfont\huge\filcenter\bfseries}
{\thechapter}
{0.5em}
{}
```